# Angular2 component templateUrl in npm package

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, systemjs, angular2-components

I am writing a common used component in an npm module, and I don't know what is the best way to refer to `templateUrl`, it is working but **I don't want to include `node_modules` in `templateUrl`,** because node_module direcotry can be renamed.

Is there an other working way to use it?

For instance: `"npm:my-commons-ts/my-commons/components/BootstrapAlert/BootstrapAlert.html"`

```
@Component({
    selector: "bs-alert",
    templateUrl: "node_modules/my-commons-ts/my-commons/components/BootstrapAlert/BootstrapAlert.html",
})
export class BootstrapAlertComponent {

  public errors: DisplayMessage[] = [];
  public successes: DisplayMessage[] = [];
  public warnings: DisplayMessage[] = [];
  public infos: DisplayMessage[] = [];

  @Input()
  public bcn: string = null;

  ...
}
```

I use `systemjs` to load modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates aren't loaded via SystemJS so you can't use its mapping.

Note that you can use relative paths, for example `../BootstrapAlert/BootstrapAlert.html` and there are also template inliners for certain build tools such as [`gulp-angular-embed-templates`](https://github.com/laxa1986/gulp-angular-embed-templates) for `gulp`.

Comment: If you are planning to publish the component embedding the template is the way to go. Webpack/Angular-cli users have had problems with modules I have published which had relative paths to templates in them.